# Trying to print a word backwards but I keep getting [segmentation fault [core dumped]] among other things

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to reverse the order of letters given by the user, but I keep getting [segmentation fault [core dumped]] on some results and just the last few letters on others, the only word size that seems to work is 9 letters. For this I needed to use a while loop and ask the user how long the word is, so I can't use a more condensed function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    //intitializes variables for loops
    int a, b, d;
    int c = 0;
    int x = 0;

    //initializes other variables and the arrays
    int length = 0;
    int wordSize[length];
    int wordReverse[length];

    //asks user how long the word they want to use is
    printf("How long is the word you would like to print backwards?:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    length = x;

    //Takes the letters from the user
    for(a = 0; a < length; a = a + 1){
        printf("Please enter letter %d: ", a + 1);
        scanf(" %c", &wordSize[a]);
    }

    //returns the word that was given by user
    printf("Your word is ");
    for(b = 0; b < length; b++){
        printf(" %c", wordSize[b]);

    }

    printf("\nYour word reversed is:");
    //inserts letters into the second array array backwards
    while(c < length) {
        wordReverse[c] = wordSize[length - c];
        printf(" %c", wordReverse[c]);
        c++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this looks troublesome: `int length = 0; int wordSize[length];`

Comment: That and `int wordReverse[length];`. Two int arrays have been created of length `0`.

Comment: Aesthetic note: there is no need in modern C to declare all of your variables at the beginning of the function. And as `a` and `b` appear to have no relevance outside of the loops they're used in, they can be locally scoped to those loops.

Comment: You need to learn a lot about parsing input, string operations and memory management. I suggest you go follow the curriculum of a C course without skipping steps. If you learned this from a course, pick a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this part of the code:

```c
 //initializes other variables and the arrays
    int length = 0;
    int wordSize[length];
    int wordReverse[length];
```

As you can see, `length` is 0, so `wordSize` and `wordReverse` are gonna be empty arrays. You'd need to create a dynamic array or use a hardcoded size to store your input.

You are accessing some random addresses at the moment which don't belong to your program.

So in your case, I'd change it to the following code:

```c
    int length = 0;
    char * wordSize;
    char * wordReverse;

    //asks user how long the word they want to use is
    printf("How long is the word you would like to print backwards?:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    // don't forget the null-terminating string!
    length = x;

    wordSize = malloc(length + 1);
    wordReverse = malloc(length + 1);

    if (wordSize == NULL || wordReverse == NULL)
        return 1;
```

Comment: Don't forget to `free()` the memory from `malloc()` when done.